# Different compile outcomes when dealing with incomplete type of const/non-const references to templated type

Tags: c++

I've written some codes like the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A;
struct B;

template <typename T>
struct Base;

struct Visitor {
  virtual void Visit(const Base<A> & a);
  virtual void Visit(const Base<B> & b);
};

template <typename T>
struct Base {
  T val;
  virtual void Accept(Visitor& v) {
    v.Visit(*this);
  }
};

struct A {
  int a;
};

void Visitor::Visit(const Base<A> & a) {
    cout<<"Base<A> visited"<<endl;
}

void Visitor::Visit(const Base<B> & b) {
    cout<<"Base<B> visited"<<endl;
}

int main() {
  Visitor v;
  Base<A> a;

  a.Accept(v);

  return 0;
}
```

With g++ 7.5.0 / Ubuntu 18.04, it cannot compile. g++ complains that `Base<T>::val` has incomplete type.

But if I remove const-qualifiers of arguments of `Visitor::Visit`, it then can compile and will give out expected result (prints "Base visited"). What's the difference between const and non-const references in such case?

Full compiler error message:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Base<B>’:
test.cpp:20:5:   required from ‘void Base<T>::Accept(Visitor&) [with T = A]’
test.cpp:41:13:   required from here
test.cpp:18:5: error: ‘Base<T>::val’ has incomplete type
   T val;
     ^~~
test.cpp:5:8: note: forward declaration of ‘struct B’
 struct B;
        ^
```

---

### Updates

Thanks to @Oblivion & @j6t. Your answer inspire me.

I changed my codes to make it more concise and less noise about the problem:

```cpp
struct A;
struct B;

template <typename T>
struct Base;

void func(const Base<A> & a) {
}

void func(const Base<B> & b) {
}

template <typename T>
struct Base {
  T value;
};

struct A {};

int main() {
  func(Base<A>{});
  return 0;
}
```

It will produce the same error. So I think the key is about function overload resolution.

Here's my reasoning: When calling `func(Base<A>{})`, the compiler needs to look up overloads candidates. For `const Base<B>&`, implicit conversions need to be considered because const reference can bind on rvalue.

So the compiler needs to instantiate `Base<B>` to see if there's any such conversions. Because of the member `T val;` in the general `Base` template, `B` is required to be complete. And that's where the compile error comes.

For `Base<B>&`, only lvalue of `Base<B>` is accepted. The compiler don't need to look up for implicit conversion and no instantiation of `Base<B>` is needed.

Comment: please incldue the compiler error message in the question

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the incomplete type the standard requires in your case:

> 3.2 One definition rule [basic.def.odr]
>
> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to an lvalue referring to an
> object of type T (4.1)

your function can be invoked like this:

```
a.Accept(Visitor{});
```

If you remove the `const` from the function signature then such call is not accepted. So that's why per standard you need complete type.

---

you can use pointer if you need to deal with incomplete type:

```
  virtual void Visit(const Base<A>* a);
  virtual void Visit(const Base<B>* b);
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ch77vb)

Comment: Yes, I've tried switching to pointers and it work both w./w.o. const. I'm just curious about why the compiler work that way with references.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `Visitor::Visit(const Base<B> &)` instantiates `Base<B>`. That needs a definition of `B`, but you have not provided one.

Read all the error messages, I am pretty sure that the compiler tells you the same thing.

Comment: But it complains nothing if I just remove the const-qualifiers.